# Show this matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix
\begin{equation}
S_n = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{1}{2!} & \frac{1}{3!} & \cdots & \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \\
   \frac{1}{3!} & \frac{1}{4!} & \cdots & \frac{1}{(n+2)!} \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   \frac{1}{(n+1)!} & \frac{1}{(n+2)!} & \cdots & \frac{1}{2n!} \\
  \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

I am interested to know if $S_n$ is invertible for all $n$. I do not need the inverse explicitly, knowing it exists is sufficient (ie. non-zero determinant for all $n$ is enough).

If this matrix has a special name, I would appreciate if someone could bring it to my attention.

Comment: It is invertible.

Comment: @TheDeadLegend, why? And I feel like a good starting place for this matrix is that it is symmetric and Hermitian.

Comment: @Joel Related https://oeis.org/A067689, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HilbertMatrix.html

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: this is not a Hilbert matrix at all.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Not exactly a Hilbert Matrix, I know, That's why I spoke of "related" material which it definitely is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $k\le n$, define a $k\times k$ matrix as follows:
$$
A_k=\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n-k+2)!} &\dfrac{(n+2)!}{(n-k+3)!} &\cdots &\cdots &\dfrac{(n+k)!}{(n+1)!}\\
\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n-k+3)!} &\dfrac{(n+2)!}{(n-k+4)!} &\cdots &\cdots &\dfrac{(n+k)!}{(n+2)!}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots\\
\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n-1)!} &\dfrac{(n+2)!}{n!} &\cdots &\cdots &\dfrac{(n+k)!}{(n+k-2)!}\\
\dfrac{(n+1)!}{n!} &\dfrac{(n+2)!}{(n+1)!} &\cdots &\cdots &\dfrac{(n+k)!}{(n+k-1)!}\\
1&1&\cdots&\cdots&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since $A_n=S_n\operatorname{diag}\left((n+1)!,(n+2)!,\ldots,(2n)!\right)$, it suffices to show that $A_k$ is invertible for each $1\le k\le n$. We shall prove this by mathematical induction. The base case $k=1$ (with $A_1=[1]$) is trivial. For the inductive step, subtract every $j$-th column (with $j\ge2$) by the column on its left to obtain
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n-k+2)!} &\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n-k+3)!}(k-1) &\cdots &\cdots &
\dfrac{(n+k-1)!}{(n+1)!}(k-1)\\
\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n-k+3)!} & \dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n-k+4)!}(k-2) &\cdots &\cdots &\dfrac{(n+k-1)!}{(n+2)!}(k-2)\\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots\\
\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n-1)!} &\dfrac{(n+1)!}{n!}(2) &\cdots &\cdots &\dfrac{(n+k-1)!}{(n+k-2)!}(2)\\
n+1 &1 &\cdots &\cdots &1\\
\hline
1&0&\cdots&\cdots&0
\end{array}\right].
$$
Now we are done because the top right sub-block of this matrix is $\operatorname{diag}(k-1,k-2,\ldots,1)A_{k-1}$. This proof also shows that $|\det S_n|=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(k-1)!}{(n+k)!}$.

Comment: I am just curious to know. How come this solution came to your mind? I mean I can never thought of such solution. What is the secret and motivation to reach to this level. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @srijan There is no secret. Fractions are difficult to work with, so we divide each column of $S_n$ by the bottom entry in the column to get an integer matrix $A_n$. Now it is a rather common technique to prove that a determinant is nonzero by performing row/column operations to the matrix.

Comment: thanks @user1551, I enjoyed your solution. This question is related to some research of mine and I would like to credit the solution to you. Please contact me (details in profile) to discuss, else I will credit your user name. Thanks!

Comment: @Joel Thanks, but I'd like to remain anonymous. For citation, a line like "this fact was explained to us by "`user1551`" in an answer (`https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2260727`) on `math.stackexchange.com`" should be more than enough. Footnote 7 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.0325v2.pdf) is a real-life citation example of this sort. [This question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4259) also has a discussion about citing MSE.